# Modify HTML file and then get the modified html as an output

Tags: jsoup

I am new to jsoup so I am a little bit confused as to how to apply the modification to the original HTML file and then get it as an output.

After giving changes by selecting the portion of html

e.g. `Element elements = doc.select("_____").attr("_____",____);`
(As this elements would only have the selected portion...)

how can I apply this to the original doc? so that I can get the modified HTML as an output?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The changes are applied to the doc as you make them. For example, I start off with this:

```
String html = "<html>" +
        "<body>" +
        "<p class=\"class1\">p1</p>" +
        "<p class=\"class2\">p2</p>" +
        "</body>" +
        "</html>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
System.out.println(doc);
```

It outputs:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p class="class1">class1</p>
  <p class="class2">class2</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now I make some changes to the p elements:

```
Element p1 = doc.select("p.class1").first();
p1.attr("class", "classOne");

Element p2 = doc.select("p.class2").first();
p2.attr("id", "helloworld");

System.out.println(doc);
```

The output is different to reflect the changes I made to its Elements:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p class="classOne">p1</p>
  <p class="class2" id="helloworld">p2</p>
 </body>
</html>
```